# Change WooCommerce email subject for specific category?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a client that would like to have the email subject of WooCommerce reflect the category of the product purchased.

I have seen code specific to one category, but I am not sure how to change it so that the subject line would change based on whichever category the product is.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'custom_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);
function custom_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    $backordered = false;

    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        if ( has_term( 'preorder', 'product_cat' , $item->get_product_id() ) ) { 
            $backordered = true;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if ( $backordered ) {  
        $subject = sprintf( '[PO]New customer order (# %s) from %s %s', $order->get_id(), $order->get_billing_first_name(), $order->get_billing_last_name() );
    } 
    return $subject;
}
```